# geom_tile do not display the map

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, maps

I have [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6258283/Test_Geom_Tile.csv) data. I am trying to plot a facet map using following codes.
Unfortunately it does not show the tiles plot i e do not give the maps. What is give is here. It only show the legend. 
What is wrong? how to fix this?
thank you,
a
The code used is

```
geomerror<-read.csv("Test_Geom_Tile.csv")
str(geomerror)
plot<- ggplot(geomerror,aes(x=Longitude,y=Latitude))+
  geom_tile(aes(fill=Value),alpha=0.6)+
  facet_wrap(~Par)+
  scale_fill_gradientn(name="Test",     colours=rev(brewer.pal(11,rev("RdYlBu"))),breaks=seq(-10,15,by=5))+
  coord_fixed()
plot
```

[image: What i got is here, this do not show map]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that your data for the different Par values is on different grids. The `geom_tile` layer expects all observations to have the same sets of x/y values. This is not the case in your data. Your values for AA and CC match, thus you can plot

```
ggplot(subset(geomerror,Par%in%c("AA", "CC")),aes(x=Longitude,y=Latitude))+
  geom_tile(aes(fill=Value),alpha=0.6)+
  facet_wrap(~Par)+
  scale_fill_gradientn(name="Test", colours=rev(brewer.pal(11,rev("RdYlBu"))),breaks=seq(-10,15,by=5))+
  coord_fixed()
```

same goes for BB and DD

```
ggplot(subset(geomerror,Par%in%c("BB", "DD")),aes(x=Longitude,y=Latitude))+
  geom_tile(aes(fill=Value),alpha=0.6)+
  facet_wrap(~Par)+
  scale_fill_gradientn(name="Test", colours=rev(brewer.pal(11,rev("RdYlBu"))),breaks=seq(-10,15,by=5))+
  coord_fixed()
```

But unless you can align them to the same grid, you cannot plot them using facets. You may consider using `grid.arrage` from the `gridExtra` package to layout 4 separate plots in the same configuration.